# How to save value for a Specific[custom] Product Attribute from Product Model

Tags: product, attributes

How to save value  for a **Specific[custom] Product Attribute** from Product Model ?

I have found the below script from [here](http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/saving-the-value-of-a-specific-attribute-from-a-model) :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); 

$product->setName('Some Random Name'); 

$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'name');
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are 2 ways to go about this, one is by getting the Magento `catalog/product` model and loading the product by ID which will give you the whole product, then setting the name and saving it.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
$product->setName('foobar!');

try {
   $product->save();
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo "{$e}";
}
```

As OP pointed out, this is quite heavy just for changing one attribute. I kind of figured that the attribute mass update tool should use a cleaner way to do this and found the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Action` class

```
$product_id = 1;
$store_id = 0;

$action = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product_action');
$action->updateAttributes(array($product_id), array(
    'name' => 'foobar!'
), $store_id);
```

**[UPDATE] benchmark**

So did a quick benchmark script and the results speak for itself.

```
$starttime = microtime(true);

for ($i=20; $i>0; $i--)
{
    $action = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product_action');
    $action->updateAttributes(array(1), array(
        'name' => 'foobar!'
    ), 0);
}

echo "Time: " . (microtime(true) - $starttime) . " seconds\n";

$starttime = microtime(true);

for ($i=20; $i>0; $i--)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
    $product->setName('foobar!');
    $product->save();
    unset($product);
}

echo "Time: " . (microtime(true) - $starttime) . " seconds\n";
```

> Time: 0.076527833938599 seconds
>
> Time: 4.757472038269 seconds

Comment: Thanks for the reply But above script takes more time since its loads the model .Thanks for the reply But above script takes more time since its loads the model .

Comment: I've done an update of the code

Comment: You're welcome. I actually already implemented in 2 import scripts and it saves a lot of time.

Comment: Small question: this was not the answer you were looking for? If not let me know, if so please close the question to keep our Answered question rate up :)

Answer (score 11):

If you need to save just one attribute and you already have the product loaded you can use also this method:

```
$product->setData('attribute_code',$someData);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product,'attribute_code');
```

This method is much faster than  `catalog/resource_product_action`

Comment: Thank you for the post and keeping it up-to-date. But i see a strange behavior. Like this save always gave me the best time. But lately in 2 Magento instances EE ones this too takes time to complete the Save. Could it be due to some extension on these instance. I can think of no other issue. These Magento instances are currently on by local dev system and am yet to transfer it to a test server instance.

Comment: @Fra you should run the same benchmark that Sander ran - would be a good comparison!