# How can I update the selected Item price in manage categories?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, php-5.4

I am new to magento, In magento admin panel -> manage categories-> I have added the new action as Update Price. when I given a amount and submit the button the selected item price will be update/decrease?

but it's not working for me can any one tell me how can I do this?

this is my code

```
  array_unshift($statuses, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('price', array(
        'label'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Update Price'),
        'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massPrice', array('_current'=>true)),
        'additional' => array(
            'visibility' => array(
                'name' => 'price',
                'type' => 'text',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
                'values' => $statuses
            )
        )
    ));
```

see image 
[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you also post the code that is doing the actual update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean 'manage products' not 'manage categories'.
You need to implement the method `massPriceAction` either in the admin product controller ([by overwriting it](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/)), or your custom controller and change `'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massPrice', array('_current'=>true)),` to the appropriate value. The in the `massPriceAction` put a code similar to this (you may need to tweak it a little ):

```
$productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
$priceChange =$this->getRequest()->getParam('price');//or however the price you send field is named 
if (!is_array($productIds)) {
    $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please select product(s).'));
} elseif (empty($priceChange)) {
    $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Fill in the price change field'));
}
    if (!empty($productIds)) {
        try {
            $action = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product_action');
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('price')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$productIds));
            foreach ($collection as $product) {
                $action->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('price' => $product->getPrice() + $priceChange ), 0);
            }
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Total of %d record(s) have been deleted.', count($productIds))
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
$this->_redirect('*/catalog_product/index');
```

Thanks @SanderMangel for suggesting the faster version.

Comment: The whole category thing kinda left me puzzled. Updating products makes more sense :) To speed up your code above I would recommend using some method I found out a while back (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8199/how-to-save-value-for-a-specificcustom-product-attribute-from-product-model/8202#8202)
as it doesn't require you to load the whole product. It's actually used by Magento for the mass attribute update

Comment: @SanderMangel I agree. It's faster to use the mass update. But in this case you still need to load the product to get the original price. I've updated the answer to use both.

Comment: Ah you're right. wouldn't it be faster in this case to get a collection, filter on ID's and just add the price field as addAttributeToSelect then iterate through that? Sorry for carrying on but I gfind these cases interresting :)

Comment: @SanderMangel D'oh!....you're right. I will change the answer.

Comment: I'll leave you alone now ;)

Comment: hello marius & sander it's working fine. thank you :)